# pd.datetime is failing to convert to date

Tags: dataframe, python-datetime

I have a data frame, which has a column 'Date', it is a `string` type, and as I want to use the column 'Date' as index, first I want to convert it to `datetime`, so I did:

```
data['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(data['Date'])
```

then I did,

```
data = data.set_index('Date')
```

but when I tried to do

```
data =  data.loc['01/06/2006':'09/06/2006',]
```

the slicing is not accomplished, there is no Error but the slicing doesn't occur, I tried with `iloc`

```
data =  data.iloc['01/06/2006':'09/06/2006',]
```

and the error message is the following:

```
TypeError: cannot do slice indexing on <class `'pandas.tseries.index.DatetimeIndex'> with these indexers [01/06/2006] of <type 'str'>`
```

So I come to the conclusion that the `pd.to_datetime` didn't work, even though no Error was raised?

Can anybody clarify what is going on? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you need change order of `datetime` string to `YYYY-MM-DD`:

```
data =  data.loc['2006-06-01':'2006-06-09']
```

Sample:

```
data = pd.DataFrame({'col':range(15)}, index=pd.date_range('2006-06-01','2006-06-15'))
print (data)
           col
2006-06-01    0
2006-06-02    1
2006-06-03    2
2006-06-04    3
2006-06-05    4
2006-06-06    5
2006-06-07    6
2006-06-08    7
2006-06-09    8
2006-06-10    9
2006-06-11   10
2006-06-12   11
2006-06-13   12
2006-06-14   13
2006-06-15   14

data =  data.loc['2006-06-01':'2006-06-09']
print (data)

            col
2006-06-01    0
2006-06-02    1
2006-06-03    2
2006-06-04    3
2006-06-05    4
2006-06-06    5
2006-06-07    6
2006-06-08    7
2006-06-09    8
```

Comment: Hello @jezrael, thanks for your help, I tried this `data1 =  data.loc['2006-06-01':'2006-06-09']` and the outcome is the data only for '2006-06-06'.

Comment: I also then tried `data = data[data.Date.between('2006-06-01','2006-06-09')]` which brings the same result, data for  '2006-06-06'. I should mention that, there is also another column with times from 0 to 24h in 10 minutes intervals for each day

Comment: Hmmm, what return `data1 = data.loc['2006-06-01']` ?

Comment: When I do that I get, `KeyError: 'the label [2006-06-01] is not in the [index]'`

Comment: I think that it has taken the format YYYY-DD-MM... because it returns results for ["2006-12-06"] but after ["2006-13-06"]  I get the same Error above

Comment: Definitely it's mixing up the formats, if I do `data.index` I get the values '2006-05-31'... '2006-01-07' in which the last one should be '2006-07-01' as I know that I am analyzing data for the month of June

Comment: I think you need parameter `dayfirst=True` in [to_datetime](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_datetime.html), then it should works nice. Can you check it?

Answer (score 0):

As I what I want is to create a new DataFrame with specific dates from the original DataFrame, I convert the column 'Date' as Index

```
data = data.set_index(data['Date'])
```

And then just create the new Data Frame using `loc`

```
data1 =  data.loc['01/06/2006':'09/06/2006']
```

I am quite new to Python and I thought that I needed to convert to `datetime` the column 'Date' which is `string`, but apparently is not necessary. Thanks for your help @jezrael